# Disable Integrity Check On Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 ISO?

Tags: server, system-installation, disk-check

Trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 from ISO virtually mounted at ILO4. I get this integrity check, which takes ages How to skip?
[Integrity Check Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJY1W.png)

It's insane. Takes more than half an hour now and nothing...

Comment: No. This is when booting from virtual media (imitating CD) on a server when trying to install the OS.

Comment: Additional info belongs as an edit to the question not as a comment.

Comment: Are you installing onto bare metal? Or into a VM or container? Your output indicates that your system disabled caching, so yes the check is going to take a long time.

Comment: I went out shopping and it finished. Now I am installing. Yes - on bare metal. Would be good to know how to skip this. Also there appears to be 20.04.2 installer, which is being downloaded now. Strange. It is not available on the ubuntu site, yet.

Answer (score 14):

I was plagued with this issue as well, would easily take 40+ minutes for the check to finish when using IPMI virtual media.

I believe I've found a workaround for now.

1. Spam press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as soon as you see the purple screen appear after booting from ISO. You should see the following screen after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

   [image]
2. Select your language, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then, once the screen is at *Install Ubuntu Server*, select *F6 Other Options*:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the dialog box in the bottom left corner. At this point, you should be able to type on the line that starts with `Boot Options...`. Replace `quiet` with `fsck.mode=skip`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

   [image]

At this point you should be able to boot without disk verification which is very fast over an IPMI-mounted disk.

Comment: At the grub prompt for install ubuntu server you need to hit 'e' then add "fsck.mode=skip" immediately before "quiet" (add a space before and after "fsck.mode=skip") then hit F10 or ctrl+x, I tried adding it to the very bottom and it didn't work, more info here : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/1892369/comments/21

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me without having to do it before the Grub menu.  I just hit F6 a couple more times after inputting the line of text at the bottom and it takes right off. One thing to note if you are using SuperMicro IPMI, is to change your Hot Key for F6 (other wise it will reboot).

Great fix!

Answer (score 0):

If you get the grub menu (as opposed to the purple screen) :
[image: Grub screen]

then enter `e` to edit and replace `quiet` with `fsck.mode=skip`

[image: boot parameters]

then continue with the boot...